# creating CSV with C# from seperate strings

Tags: c#, csv

I want to build a CSV file from separate strings but since the size of the string is big I'm trying to avoid from joining the strings into a single string before writing to the file. Meaning, creating a file and than adding another string into it.
can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using String go for `StringBuilder` to build your string.

than flush string in file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the StreamWriter object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Have a look [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter) as well

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [StreamWriter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) then simply call [Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce2kyyb4.aspx) method each time you want to write value to file.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/7624-Reading-Writing-Appending-Text-File-Using-c.aspx/) is a full demo for creating a text file, including a function for appending strings to it after creation.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this coding.

```
 StringBuilder Content1 = new StringBuilder();
 Content1.Append("MailFrom:" + FromAdd + Constants.vbCrLf);
 Content1.Append("MailTo:" + EmailID + Constants.vbCrLf);
 Content1.Append("MailCC:" + MailCC + Constants.vbCrLf);
 Content1.Append("MailBCC:" + MailBCC + Constants.vbCrLf);
 Content1.Append("MailSubject:" + MailSubject + RequestNumber + Constants.vbCrLf);
 Content1.Append("MailAttachment:" + MailAttachment + Constants.vbCrLf);
 Content1.Append("MailBody:" + "" + Constants.vbCrLf);
 if (!File.Exists(Application.StartupPath)) {
SW = File.CreateText(Application.StartupPath + "\\" + FinalPath);
using (fs) {
}
Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
  using (SW) {
SW.Write(Content1.ToString);
 }
```

Use the above method for creating a text file and writing the content.

Comment: Why are you creating an email?